# How can I make my "AI" do an action until certain criteria are met?

Tags: c, loops, conditional-statements

This is a player vs AI tic-tac-toe game in C. If the AI rolls into an occupied spot, how do I make it so that it rolls again until it reaches an unoccupied spot?

```
char boardchar[3][3] = { {'1', '2', '3'}, {'4', '5', '6'}, {'7', '8', '9'} }; 


void Turn()
{
    /*Player's Turn*/

    AIrandomizer();
    AI = AI_roll();


        if (AI == 1 && boardchar[0][0] == '1')
        {
            boardchar[0][0] = symbAI;
        }

        else if (AI == 2 && boardchar[0][1] == '2')
        {
            boardchar[0][1] = symbAI;                   
        }


        else if (AI == 3 && boardchar[0][2] == '3')
        {
            boardchar[0][2] = symbAI;               
        }


        else if (AI == 4 && boardchar[1][0] == '4')
        {
            boardchar[1][0] = symbAI;       
        }

        else if (AI == 5 && boardchar[1][1] == '5')
        {
            boardchar[1][1] = symbAI;               
        }


        else if (AI == 6 && boardchar[1][2] == '6')
        {
            boardchar[1][2] = symbAI;               
        }

        else if (AI == 7 && boardchar[2][0] == '7')
        {
            boardchar[2][0] = symbAI;               
        }

        else if (AI == 8 && boardchar[2][1] == '8')
        {
            boardchar[2][1] = symbAI;               
        }

        else if (AI == 9 && boardchar[2][2] == '9')
        {
            boardchar[2][2] = symbAI;           
        }

}
```

I've tried switch(case) and multiple ifs and else ifs but I still can't manage to figure out a way to fix this issue.

Comment: Put a `while(1) { ... }` around the relevant code and when you find a free spot do a return

Comment: *"it rolls again until..."* - This statement implies a loop, but none has been written.

Comment: Your "AI" is basically just rolling a random number? Get rid of `boardchar[0][0] == '1'`, `boardchar[0][1] == '2'`, this doesn't make sense, you shouldn't have numbers written to the board in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a while or do-while statement.

Also make a 3x3 twodimensional array that keeps track of the spots: 0 = unfilled, 1 = Human, 2 = AI (better is to use an enum).

In pseudo code:

Global variable:

```
int spots[3][3]; // 3x3 array
```

Code:

```
Setup(); // Setup of board, sets 0's to spots.

while (!endOfGame())
{
    Player(); // Handle player, assuming it plays first, sets a 1 in one spot

    if (!endOfGame())
    {
         AI();
    }
}


void AI() 
{
    do
    {
       square = AIChoice();
    } while (spots[square] == 0);

    // Now we know spots[square] == 0, thus unfilled
    spots[square] = 2; // AI
}
```

Comment: If `AIChoice` is random, as it probably is with OP's code, this will work (so +1 from me), but won't make much sense otherwise. Alternative approach with a random "AI" would be to count empty slots before rolling (`E`) and then roll a random number from `0` to `E-1`, this would make it `O(1)` complexity for the fixed board size, but would make the code a bit more complex.

Comment: @Groo I didn't focus much on the random part, because I assume (hope) that the random will just be be an 'initial' version, later I hope a better implementation will be used. Although your solution is indeed better in performance, for O(n) where n is less than 9 on average, most CPUs will not having a problem. In theory my algorithm could never finish though.